# Term to describe breaking a number into its constituent digits?

Tags: terminology

I'm writing a program, and in this program is a method that takes a number (say, 1,337), and returns its digits (1, 3, 3, and 7).

Is there a mathematical term that describes this process? If not, is there a word that at least describes a good part of the process? (perhaps decimate, addendize, decompose, depose)

I've seen the term "digit expansion", which sounds like it might be what I'm looking for, but attempts to find a definition of this term on the internet only return documents where it is used in context, and not an official definition.

Keep in mind, attempts to find an appropriate term have also been inhibited by my limited mathematical vocabulary in general, so I apologize if this is really simple.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you use "expansion" it should be "_decimal_ expansion". Numbers have binary expansions also, and so on. The Wikipedia article discusses only the decimal expansion of fractional numbers, which is regrettable.